# bash script is not reading or parsing string containing a exclamation mark ! and asterisk *

Tags: shell-script

I wrote an ldap search bash script with search scope/filter that contains exclamation mark '!' and asterisk '*'. Something like this and the script is not reading the string between double quotes correctly. The same filter works just fine when I pass in the command line:

```
"(&(objectclass=*)(uid=*)("\!"(roles=*)))"
```

Here's the complete ldapsearch query that is being run in bash script:

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 389 -D "cn=ldapadm,o=proxy" -W - -b "ou=users,o=org" -s sub -LLL "(&(objectclass=*)(uid=*)("\!"(roles=*)))" | grep dn:
```

Comment: Is the `!` supposed to be escaped? Are the double quotes around `\!` supposed to be part of the string? In that case, use single quotes around the option argument to `-LLL`.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes as content in double quotes is interpolated by the shell and a star or a bang has a specific meaning for it.

```
-LLL '(&(objectclass=*)(uid=*)("\!"(roles=*)))'
```

I do not know if your inside double quotes are necessary, you will probably need to remove them as well, so in fact the syntax should be:

```
-LLL '(&(objectclass=*)(uid=*)(!(roles=*)))'
```

Comment: Yes I tried and it didn't work:

    '(&(objectclass=*)(cn=*)(!(naX509UserCertificate=*)))'

Comment: I also tried these and it didn't work:

    '(&(objectclass=*)(cn=*)("/!"(naX509UserCertificate=*)))'
    '(&(objectclass=*)(cn=*)(/!(naX509UserCertificate=*)))'

Comment: Does not work as in "error by the shell" or "not giving the results I expected back from the LDAP server"? These are two different things. Please update your question with more specific details. I think that `'(&(objectclass=*)(cn=*)(!(naX509UserCertificate=*)))' ` is fine regarding syntax.

Comment: There's no error by the shell... it is simply not giving expected result. If I run the same filter in a command line it works just fine

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand you on the two opposing cases you write about (shell vs command line). Without way more details about exactly what you input where, I fear not to be able to help you. Maybe someone else will better understand than me.

Comment: @Riz You've changed your query here in comments. It no longer has `roles` in it. You need to be consistent.